# Class Not Found running Scala in IntelliJ SBT project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Apologies as this is a newby question. I have the following SBT project containing a scala object. When I run 'Hi'  I get "Class not found" exception. Where to specify the class path?

[click here to see the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGM0W.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete this object and create a new one. Right click on src->main->scala(NOT in target folder) folder new -> Scala class -> type "Hi" in name field in check box choose object.  And paste your:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) = println("hi")
```

Comment: I don't see "Scala Class", only "Scala Worksheet" and "Scala Script" that's probably the problem, how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like you SBT didn't make a project yet. Open build.sbt and in top right corner you should have some blue popup with button like build or download dependencies. Or try Ctrl+Alt+Y

Comment: It worked!! By the way, there are two directories scala and scala-211, when to use each? thanks

Comment: Both of them work, just put all your source files to one of them and when you will write unit test put them in corresponding folder test/scala or test/ scala-211

Answer (score 0):

This could be because main method doesn't have return type, try adding `Unit` so I must be like this:

```
def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = println("hi")
```

regards